# Eclipse Java - Android - Source Not found

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Please dont mark this as duplicate. Its not. Nothing described in the other solutions works.

I recently installed Eclipse & Android SDK studio. Now as I am setting up to debug the code .. It is giving "Source not found".. the code which crashes the code 'eventually' is the basic textView

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

these are the tabs open and the thread situation.

[image]

Comment: why use eclipse rather you can use Android studio, google has stopped its support to eclipse android studio is there official android IDE

Comment: Could you please post some versions i.e. Eclipse version, Android SDK version etc.

Comment: Try clicking "Edit Source Lookup Path"

Comment: `PhoneWindow` class is a native Android class that has been compiled to binary jar file, so you can't see its source code. You can only source codes of your own classes and activities.

Comment: Vishwajit Palankar People use eclipse because they are or used to be Java developers and get used that IDE which is one of the best

Comment: "Nothing described in the other solutions works." You're going to have to be more specific about that. Exactly what was tried, and exactly how did it not work? Otherwise... this IS a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Attaching Java Source to Android projects in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182904/attaching-java-source-to-android-projects-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, are you trying to cast a TextView to an EditText?
Make sure you have create a TextView and not an EditText in your layout.

Also make sure you have set your layout as content view.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```